# indexpath row not getting in prepare for segue for detail disclosure

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Edit"]){

    AddCoffeeViewController *avc = [segue destinationViewController];

    Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:arow];
    NSLog(@"ViewController.m prepareForSegue: arow: %d coffeeName:%@ price:%@      coffeeID:%d",arow,coffeeObj.coffeeName,coffeeObj.price,coffeeObj.coffeeID);
    [coffeeObj setIsInEditMode:YES];
    avc.EditCoffeeObj = coffeeObj;


}
```

I am not getting the correct row when i am pressing accessory button.


Although in below method i am getting the correct row.
Is there any way that i can get correct row prepare for segue if i do not want to use any ivar.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

arow = indexPath.row;

}
```

[image]

tableViewCell accessory button: Performing modal segue(Edit) 

+ Button (Navigation bar button Item): Performing modal segue(Add)

Comment: Why not just place prepare for segue directly inside accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath?

Comment: I want to pass coffee class object. if use [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Edit" sender:nil]; then is there any that i can pass Coffee class object as well.

Comment: NOTE: Calling segue from an accessory button was first introduced in iOS6. A good workaround is to create a custom cell and add a button to it and call the segue from that button.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have hooked up accessory action in your storyboard then the `sender` in `prepareForSegue:sender:` will be the cell that that was tapped. This means you can just do something like

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
```

Comment: hey your solution was correct.Thanks a lot. I don't understand why some people are giving negative post to my question.Just try it out you will face the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Accessory button tapped and selected row are two different things.  In the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath, just set the indexPath to a global variable and then use that in the segue.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3.0** Solution; Very similar to Objective-C version. So Cell is sender and we receive the **indexPath** through **Cell** in which accessory pressed

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? YourViewController {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
    }
}
```